# How can I abort a file upload that exceeds php's upload maximum?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload, upload

When uploading files that are beyond the maximum size that PHP is set to allow, typically, the entire file gets uploaded before I am able to handle a response from the server side.

In php.ini, I have maximum post size and maximum upload size set to 2 MB. When I select a file in my upload form that exceeds 2 MB (aka, a 1 GB file), the server still accepts the file, but I need to wait until the entire file has been uploaded in order to process / handle the upload event.

Now, the interesting part, is the upload progress session returns 100%, allows me to return control of the upload form (hide progress bar, show upload form and submit button again), however due to having to wait on the upload to actually finish I am unable to return a response back to the user.

For my project, there are 3 parts :

1. The upload form - This contains the code to post the upload to 'upload.php' (hidden iframe), and monitor progress on 'upload_progress.php' (XHR).
2. upload.php - This is the file handler responsible for accepting the file, and then elevate a response back to the upload form based on file type, errors, success, etc  ( cross-frame script locked to current domain and protocol ).
3. upload_progress.php - this just reads in the session data for upload progress as made available by php's uploadprogress module. Response is an integer.

The problem is that if the upload is too large, #3 shows as complete, however #2 continues to accept the data until the entire file has been uploaded.

What I would like to know, is there any way I can detect this immediately when it happens that isn't 100% dependent on JavaScript for checking the filesize before upload as this can be bypassed.  I know that I can check client side prior to the file being sent, however I would like to implement a proper server-side abort of the upload when the file is too large prior to implementing the client side abort in javascript.  Meaning, I do not want to rely on JavaScript for server safety (file types, size, etc).

Hope I explained everything well enough to understand.  I have seen this problem in PHP for many years now, and I am surprised the file upload isn't automatically aborted at the server side when the data received threshold exceeds the limits set in php.ini

In case it makes a difference, here is my PHP version details

```
PHP 5.6.17-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2016 09:10:12) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

PHP FPM (whats serving php in my apache configuration)

```
PHP 5.6.17-0+deb8u1 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Jan 13 2016 09:10:13)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v5.0.23, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Xdebug v2.3.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

And Apache (as requested)

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Nov 28 2015 14:05:48
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:37
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

Comment: Are you sure the entire file is being uploaded prior to hitting the php upload_max_filesize?  The web server passes off the upload to the PHP application, PHP is not aware of the file size prior to processing the upload.

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure.  The wait is exactly proportional to the file transfer duration.  Eg, on my network 1 GB takes about 20 minutes, after which, I get the response from my upload.php script, but not before. -- i have no idea where it is going though. I think just in memory, but no idea.

Comment: I am confident this can be reproduced fairly easily with a simple upload form, and nothing fancy like modsec / etc that can interfere with the native upload operation.

Comment: If what you say is true, then it would be a pretty pointless limit, so I can't imagine it would be a PHP issue, possibly the web server is buffering it until it passes it to PHP.  What is your web server setup (web server distro, version, PHP api)

Comment: Added web server details and php version to my question.  I am actually using php5-fpm, however the version and compile are the same, and configs are identical where it matters.

Comment: Use javascript uploader and problem disappears if user has no alternative method to do upload ... ie no file input element

Comment: Ok, hopefully someone can shed some light on it.  I'll do some testing this week, if I have time, to confirm the issue

Comment: Appreciated.  When testing Devon, test with big files --  like 400MB +, and no javascript limiters/etc client side.   ( @charlietfl - JavaScript will block this, when JavaScript is running and provided the user doesn't alter it. This is something that should be able to be done via server side as the server should not receive files larger than it is limited to).

Comment: right and my point is that 99.9% of the web uses javascript, so if the only upload ability uses javascript you won't  get over size files sent to server. If they intentionally bypass it server will end up rejecting it and error message gets passed back to user after much longer wait ... which they brought upon themselves

Comment: @charlietfl - at the expense of valuable resources being consumed on the server side.  Typical rule of coding is not to rely on JavaScript for validation.  JavaScript provides a quick client-side pre-check of the data, however the server is responsible for ensuring that all data is accurate.  Imagine a forced upload direct to form (or other form of attack) could have crippling effects, not to mention the contents of said data may take liberties on a zero-day (or earlier) exploit vector.  The safest way is for the server to restrict this and abort the connection on partial upload.

Comment: @Devon - any luck with a resolution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Javascript and check the file size before it is uploading, although this is not an example on how to abort mid-upload from the server-side.

Here is a Live example: http://codesheet.org/codesheet/E8ZwGzoV

```
<form method="post" target="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/post.php">

        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>

<div id="message"></div>

<iframe name="submit" width="100%" height="400px"></iframe>
```

The JS is here:

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function( evt ) {

    var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];

    // 1 MB = 1048576 this size is in bytes
    if(file && file.size < 2097152) {     // 2MB = 2097152

        //Submit form  
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'The File '+bytesToSize(file.size)+' is OK!';

    } 
    else 
    {

        //Prevent default and display error
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'The File '+bytesToSize(file.size)+' is to big!';
        evt.preventDefault();

    }
}, false);

function bytesToSize(bytes) {
   var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
   if (bytes == 0) return '0 Bytes';
   var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
   return Math.round(bytes / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I am already familiar with how to do these checks using JavaScript.  This does not prevent someone (attacker) from pushing a file to the form directly, aka, server side needs to actually work and stop uploads of data if the data being received exceeds X amount. As stated in my post, upload_progress is notified, however the server continues to receive the file until complete before returning control.  You can also check upload size/ etc in Flash / Java / etc.  It is a shoddy solution to depend solely on client-side for ensuring the restrictions are met.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, what you have supplied is great client-side only validation, assuming JavaScript is enabled, and that it isn't an attack being forced. Just imagine a nice DoS attack on the form using only 100 clients uploading 1 GB data of junk to a 100MB server connection (roughly max speed of 20 megabytes / sec). Since the server will still accept the file in entirety, you can see how it could very easily run out of bandwidth/etc really fast.